# Where does $\sum c_n (x+1)^n$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

We know a series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n (x+1)^n$  converges when $x = 3$.

Can we conclude if the series converges when $x = 0, 4, -5$.

---

From what I understand we get that $$|x-(-1)| < R$$ then since the series converges when $x = 3$ $$4 < R$$

Then we know the series converges for at least $$(-5 , 3]$$

With this it is pretty straightforward that we can conclude that the series converges when $x = 0$. I'm not sure what to say for $x = 4, -5$. $-5$ is an endpoint so it might be convergent there or may not. And I have no idea for $4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of $4<R$ you need $4\le R,$ and you seem to have figured that out later in your posting.

You cannot conclude that the series converges when $x=4,$ since all you know is that it converges everywhere in $(-5,3].$ Nor can you conclude that it converges for $x=-5$ or that it fails to converge if $x=4.$ One can exhibit examples for which it converges at both of those points; for example $c_n = \dfrac 1{n!}$, or for which it diverges at $-5$ (in which case $R=4$ so it must diverge at $x=4$); for example $c_n = (-1/4)^n/n$, or for which it converges at $5$ and fails to converge at $4.$